# How to interpret the USB info in my MacBook Pro's System Report?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware

I'm trying to find out if my MacBook Pro USB ports are USB3.

It seems to have two USB2 ports and one USB3 port:

[image]

But my MacBook Pro only has two USB ports. How do I interpret this report? Do I have USB3 or not? And if it's only one of them, how do I know which one?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing what make and model of Mac you have would be very helpful in deciding what you have exactly as the specifications page on that model at apple.com would have the info you seek.

But a little interpretation of your screenshot will show that you have two USB busses. One has your FaceTime camera (the camera built into iMacs and MacBooks) and one with the keyboard and IR receiver (that is built into MacBooks).

Note that there is nothing under the USB 3.0 bus, which likely means there is nothing plugged into either of your USB ports (amiright?). So plug a USB 3 device into one of these ports and bring this report up again. Then try it in the other port. If they show up under the USB 3 bus then both ports are USB 3.

Or you could just google your Mac's make and model and follow the link to Apple's support site with the specifications of your Mac.